# How to make AutocompleteArrayInput allow new values?

Tags: react-admin

I would like to be able to enter text that doesn't match any of the autocomplete choices, and upon pressing enter, the new text should be added (and selected) as a choice.
How can I do that with AutocompleteArrayInput ? Can you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I made a Select-component that can do this, if placed inside a  component. You can find it here: https://github.com/gartner/palustris-ra-react-select

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but it might give some hints as to where to start.